# what is the shortest hash/

Tags: php, hash

Is there any hashing method for php to hash (just integer to string) in shortest lenght?

for example

input : `10565` 
output : `rwk4`

input : `40853353246`
output : `orhg0ut04h`

if there is not hashing like this

Is there any way(function) to do it?

Comment: No there's not. You can write your own function for this.

Comment: You *could* use [`pack()`](http://php.net/pack) - but what is its purpose?

Comment: With short hashes like that, the possibility of a collision rises enormously. Such hashes would only be useful for a very specialised use case. What exactly *is* your use case...?!

Comment: You could make a one byte hash with `$n % 256`, but I doubt in usefulness of such hashes.

Comment: Not to mention... if the output length varies with the input length then **it's not a hash**, it's an *encoding*. Are you looking for Base 64 encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the base_convert function for what you want, but note that a hash is something else entirely.